# Is there any way to stop or pause Windows software raid re-synching?

Tags: windows, raid, software-raid

I have two physical disks, each one holds two volumes, they are Windows software RAID1. E.g.:

> Disk A: Partition1 Partition2
>
> Disk B: Partition1-Mirror Partition2-Mirror

After an unclean reboot, Windows started resynching these as expected. What was not expected, however, is that it started resynching both volumes **at the same time**. Both disks seek back and forth like crazy, and synching performance is horrible.

**Question:** Is these any option to stop or pause synching of just one volume? I know I can put one of the disks offline, but that will stop synchronization of all volumes on that disk.

Note: I have certain reasons why I need to torture myself with Windows RAID. I'm not interested in alternative RAID solutions right now.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by "fake RAID"?  What's fake about it?

Comment: Real RAID device does all its math in hardware, and RAID arrays are presented to the OS as one disk. It handles synching, spares, etc. totally transparently to the OS, the card often has huge battery-backed cache, etc. Real RAID card is something like this: http://www.lsi.com/products/storagecomponents/Pages/MegaRAIDSAS9280-24i4e.aspx Windows with its toy immature implementation doesn't come anywhere close to a real hardware raid. But real RAID is expensive, and Windows fake-raid is built-in.

Comment: The usual term is "software RAID" as distinct from "hardware RAID".  It's still real RAID, just implemented in software.

Comment: @HarryJohnston: You're correct, I amended my question. Although Windows' software RAID/LDM can be considered "fake" if comparing to other software raid or LVM implementations :-(